# How do I pass props to another component in vue.js

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs2

I am trying to pass props from the program component to the infopanel component. There will be 5 different program components that will pass different props to the infopanel component when the program component is clicked on. I have been at this all morning and cannot figure this out. Can someone please point me in the right direction?

```js
/*
*   Components
*/


Vue.component('program', {
  data: function () {
    return {
        show: false
    }
  },
  props: {
    title: {
      type: String,
      required: false,
      default:""
    },
    imagesrc: {
      type:String,
      required:false,
      default: ""
    },
    photos: {
      type: Array, 
      default: function () {
        return [
          'https://10000leaders.com/wp-content/themes/moto/landingpage/images/eng-programs.jpg', 
          'https://10000leaders.com/wp-content/themes/moto/landingpage/images/eng-programs.jpg'
        ]
      }
    }
  },
  methods: {
      englishProgram: function () {
          this.show = true;
      }
  },
  template: `<div class='card card-default card-one'>
              <a href='javascript:;' class='card-link'>
                <span class='card-body'>
                  <span class='h3 heading'>{{ title }}</span>
                </span>
                <span class='card-img'>
                  <img class='img-responsive' :src='imagesrc'>
                </span>
              </a>
            </div>`
})  

Vue.component('infopanel', {
  data: function () {
    return {
        show: false
    }
  },
  props: {
    photos: {
      type: Array, 
      default: function () {
        return [
          'https://10000leaders.com/wp-content/themes/moto/landingpage/images/eng-programs.jpg', 
          'https://10000leaders.com/wp-content/themes/moto/landingpage/images/eng-programs.jpg'
        ]
      }
    }
  },
  methods: {
  },
  template: `<div id='infopanel'></div>`
})  

new Vue({ el: '#cards' });
```

```html
        





<div id="cards" class='cards clearfix'>
    <program title="English Program" imagesrc="<?php bloginfo('stylesheet_directory'); ?>/landingpage/images/eng-programs.jpg"></program>
    <infopanel></infopanel>
</div><!--cards-->
```

Comment: pass as a attribute

Comment: Can you explain more?

Answer (score 2):

`props` are for [parent-child communication](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/components.html#Passing-Data-to-Child-Components-with-Props). Your infopanel and program components are independent components – neither is the child of the other, so they cannot pass props to each other.

They can receive props from *their* parent, which is the root Vue instance. The program component can [emit events](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/components.html#Sending-Messages-to-Parents-with-Events) to tell the parent that it should update some value(s), which updates the props in the child components.

Comment: Thank you for the clear explanation. That makes sense.